# Windows 10 blurry windows/applications and text on full hd asus zenbook (1920 x 1080)

Tags: resolution, high-definition, 1080p

I have found alot of good solutions online, however I am unable to iron out the blurriness of a few applications.  Solutions tried:

- Right click on application -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Disable display scaling on high dpi settings. (worked great for chrome and a few other apps)
- Increase custom scaling level to 125%.  (Helped with the tiny font)

However some application (e.g. IIS) does not have that compatibility options for me to change scaling on high dpi settings.  IIS is all blurry along with a few other random Windows popups.  A few screen shots are below,  any feedback or workaround is much appreciated.  Thanks

[image]

After clicking the properties button of the image above, a clear popup appears. weird.

[image]

And an image of the blurry IIS window:

[image]